# Why is energy not conserved in some cases?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy, spring

I've got a lot of cases where the energy of the whole system is not conserved, that's probably because of some non conservative force.
One reason is that, the energy is transferred to heat, which is understandable. But in some cases, there's no heat transfer, but still the energy ain't conserved. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMVwH.png

Like in this situation. All surfaces are smooth, both forces are of different magnitude and we have to find the maximum extension. When I carry out the work energy theorem w.r.t Centre of Mass, it perfectly gives me the answer. But according to my teacher, the energy w.r.t ground is not conserved (because of two external force). But according to me, If I get to know the distances both block moved till the maximum extension w.r.t ground, I can find the work done by both forces which would be converted to P.E(negative) in blocks. Then I'll figure the work done by spring on both blocks. Should the sum of both be zero (K.Ef - K.Ei)? Should I sum up the work done on the centre of mass of whole system by the net force too? If no, what exactly makes the energy not mathematically conserved here?

Answer (score 1):

With no friction and elastic spring, mechanical energy of the system is conserved.

Let's prove it writing the dynamical equations of each block

$m_1 \ddot{x}_1 = F_{12}$
$m_2 \ddot{x}_2 = F_{21} = - F_{12}$  ,

with the force acting on mass $m_1$ due to the spring, $F_{12} = k (x_2 - x_1)$. Now, we can insert this expression in the dynamical equations above, multiplying each equation by $\dot{x}_i$

$\dot{x}_1 m_1 \ddot{x}_1 = \dot{x}_1 k (x_2 - x_1)$
$\dot{x}_2 m_2 \ddot{x}_2 = \dot{x}_2 k (x_1 - x_2)$,

and sum them,

$\dot{x}_1 m_1 \ddot{x}_1 + \dot{x}_2 m_2 \ddot{x}_2 = (\dot{x}_1 - \dot{x}_2) k (x_2 - x_1)$,

and recognize that:

- $\dot{x}_i m_i \ddot{x}_i = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} m_i \dot{x}_i^2\right) = K_i$, and
- $(\dot{x}_1 - \dot{x}_2) k (x_2 - x_1) =
     \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{1}{2} k (x_2 - x_1)^2 \right) = - \dfrac{d V^{el}}{dt}$,

we get

$0 = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( K_1 + K_2 + V^{el} \right) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( K + V^{el} \right) = \dfrac{d E^{mech}}{dt}$.

Thus, the mechanical energy, defined as the sum of the kinetic and potential energy of the system, doesn't change with time, and thus it's a conserved quantity.